# mmap file with one additional page that is not backed by the file

Tags: c++, c, linux, mmap

I need to mmap a file in read-only mode but need an additional page at the end of the mapping that is \0-ed out. My initial idea was to mmap an additional page and claim it by writing to it.

```
int file=::open(name,O_RDONLY);
size_t size=lseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
size_t pageSize=::sysconf( _SC_PAGESIZE);
int padding=size%pageSize;
size_t mapSize=size+padding+pageSize;
void* mapping=mmap(0,mapSize,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE,file,0);
*(static_cast<char*>(mapping)+size+padding+1)=0;
```

However, as stated in the mmap documentation I then get a SIGBUS when I write to the additional page (also when reading from there).

My question is, can I somehow claim an additional page after the file without modifying the actual file?

Comment: Map `/dev/zero` onto that page.

Comment: What are you attempting to use this page for?

Comment: If the file is opened read-only, can you even map it in read-write? I'd be surprised if `mmap` actually succeeded. That said, you can do as David Schwartz suggested, or you could change the file's logical size (since POSIX explicitly allows mapping any _possible_ position which does not necessarily have to exist).

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. What are you really trying to accomplish? Some sort of protection against reading past end-of-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux supports MAP_FIXED flag that forces `mmap()` segment placement, so all you need is to correctly calculate address call second `mmap()` that will map anonymous page (currently your calculation of `padding` is incorrect).

```
int file = ::open("mmap", O_RDONLY);
size_t size = ::lseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
size_t pageSize = ::sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);

int padding = pageSize - size % pageSize;
size_t mapSize = size + padding;

void* mapping = ::mmap(0, mapSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                     MAP_PRIVATE, file, 0);
void* lastPage = static_cast<char*>(mapping) + mapSize;

void* mapping2 = ::mmap(lastPage, pageSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);

* static_cast<char*>(mapping ) = 1;
* static_cast<char*>(mapping2) = 1;
```

Comment: MAP_FIXED will overwrite existing mappings which is a problem is something else is already there. Make the first mapping larger then map over the end.